# Retrieve GridPanel model/store/columns dynamically from server side

Tags: c#, extjs, extjs4

I have a GridPanel that must have its store model AND column model created dynamically, after a DB SP returns the columns of the table.

My question is how can I pass the value ( string or JSON )s from the server to the GridPanel?

```
Ext.define('Base.GridPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'gridpanel',

    flex: @BFE.Frontend.Defaults.BaseGridPanel.flex,
    hideMode: '@BFE.Frontend.Defaults.BaseGridPanel.hideMode',

    collapsible: true,

    constructor: function(id, title, columns, store) 
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.store = store;

        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

I use this custom defined GridPanel along with the following model and store for now.

```
Ext.define('Tasks', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: 
    [
        {name: 'Case_ID', type: '@MCSJS.Models.DataType.Auto'},
        {name: 'BP_Name', type: '@MCSJS.Models.DataType.Auto'},
        {name: 'Project', type: '@MCSJS.Models.DataType.Auto'},
        {name: 'Business_Unit', type: '@MCSJS.Models.DataType.Auto'},
        {name: 'Task', type: '@MCSJS.Models.DataType.Auto'},
        {name: 'Title', type: '@MCSJS.Models.DataType.Auto'},
        {name: 'Last_Edit', type: '@MCSJS.Models.DataType.Auto'},
        {name: 'Entity_Name', type: '@MCSJS.Models.DataType.Auto'},
        {name: 'Process_Instance_ID', type: '@MCSJS.Models.DataType.Auto'},
        {name: 'Start_of_Business', type: '@MCSJS.Models.DataType.Auto'},
        {name: 'Last_User', type: '@MCSJS.Models.DataType.Auto'}
    ]
});

var myTaskStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'myTasks',
    model: 'Tasks',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy:  
    {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/Task/GetMyTaskData',
        reader: 
        {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
    }
});
```

This is how I create a GridPanel :

```
var columns = [ { text: 'Case ID', dataIndex: 'Case_ID' },
                { text: 'BP Name', dataIndex: 'BP_Name' } ];
new Base.GridPanel('@BFE.Frontend.MyTask.GridPanel', 'My Tasks', columns, myTaskStore)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ext provides some support for that. You can send the model configuration by adding a [`metaData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-property-metaData) property to the server response. You can configure the name of the property with the [`metaProperty`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-cfg-metaProperty) option.

The documentation doesn't make it obvious, but you can reconfigure the fields of the model this way. Here's the kind of response that would do that:

```
{
    data: [...]

    ,metaData: {
        // This will be recognized and processed automatically
        // by the proxy
        fields: [
            {name: "id", type: "int"},
            {name: "myField", type: "string"},
            ...
        ]

        // This one is for our own usage, see bellow
        ,columns: [
            {dataIndex: "id", text: "ID},
            {dataIndex: "myField", text: "My field"},
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

As noted in the doc, when the data model changes, you'll want to update your components as well. Sencha has provided the [`metachange`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy-event-metachange) for that. Notice that, while documented in the proxy, this event will be relayed by the store.

Finally, to update the grid's column model, you have the [`reconfigure`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure) method. For example, you could modify your grid class in the following way to make it reconfigure itself automatically from the server response:

```
Ext.define('Base.GridPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel'

    // ...

    // You can add your listener in initComponent, if you're
    // reluctant to extend a method docuemented as private...
    ,bindStore: function(store) {

        // unbind previously bind store, if any
        var previous = this.getStore();
        if (previous) {
            previous.un('metachange', this.onMetaChange, this);
        }

        // bind to the meta change event
        this.getStore().on('metachange', this.onMetaChange, this);

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }

    ,onMetaChange: function(store, meta) {
        var columns = meta.columns;
        if (columns) {
            this.reconfigure(null, columns);
        }
    }
});
```

**Update**

The `onMetaChange` method is called when the `metachange` event is fired, because I have registered it as a listener with this line:

```
this.getStore().on('metachange', this.onMetaChange, this);
```

The event itself is fired when the proxy detects some meta data in the server response. Concretely, that happens when a `metaData` property (or whatever name you may have configured as the `metaProperty` of the proxy) exists in the server response.

The listener is effectively passed the raw `metaData` object, that is present in the response, as its second argument (named `meta` in my example). So your server can put any information you need in it (e.g. new field labels, tooltip texts, etc.).

`bindStore` is a method that is already present in `GridPanel`. Here I override it because I need a place to register my event listener on the store. As its name suggests, this method is called to bind a store to the component. It can be the initial store, or a new one. That's one I've preferred to override this method instead of `initComponent`. In case the store is changed later in the component life, my custom listener will be unbound from the old store and attached to the new one.

The [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) keyword is an idiosyncrasy of Javascript. It represents all the arguments that have been passed to a function. [`callParent`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Base-method-callParent) is a sweety provided by Ext to call the parent method; it takes an array as the arguments that will be passed to the parent. So `this.callParent(arguments)` calls the parent method without having to know what were precisely all the arguments of the overridden method. That's easier, and that's also more resilient to future changes, if the arguments of the method were to change...

I'd be glad to point you to a comprehensive guide about overriding in Ext... Unfortunately I couldn't find one with a quick search :-/

Comment: Hi, this is a very good answer, thank you very much. Can you clear up a few points for me? How/Where is onMetaChange called? What is the meta param in the method? Is it supposed to be the server response? Can you add a little example of how exactly it would all work together? Thank you very much, I'm a new developer and still trying to figure out things :)

Comment: Also, how should I use bindStore() and what are the arguments parameter in callParent()?

Comment: Generally, this makes sense, but I have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and clarify the points you've raised. But in order to make it work, you should (1) add a `metaData` property in your server response, probably with `fields` and `columns`, like in my example. Then (2) copy paste the two methods `bindStore` and `onMetaChange` in your own `Base.GridPanel` definition. And (3) put a `debugger` keyword in the `onMetaChange` method. There you'll be able to inspect what you have available (that should be the store and the grid itself that is the `this` scope). That should get you a long way, then you can elaborate with your own case.

Comment: @hermann So, have you eventually been able to achieve what you want, or did you meet new blockers?

Comment: thank you very much for your help, also for your update and clarifications. I followed a different approach after all.

Comment: @rixo: Please let me know what is use of `metaProperty`? I have only included `metaData` in my server response and can able to get it in onMetaChange event without setting `metaProperty`.

Comment: @PoonamBhatt The `metaProperty` option lets you use another key name for the meta in the server response. For example, you can set `metaProperty` to `'myMeta'` and use this name instead of `metaData` in your response. This is optional, and I advice against changing it if you can avoid.