# ExtJS 4.2. Grid, Store with Dynamic data loading with dynamic columns

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have one store and for grid which load data into grid. that work properly.

But My problem is i have to set grid column dynamically as i am loading columns from store.

Now first I load my store which return array for `data1` and `columns`. In Store proxy i have set reader root as data so Grid shows data properly.

Not first store loads then grid created. but I have to process `columns` before send to grid so i have written `callback` in `load` of store that work properly.

In spite for loading store with load call back first. call back return value bit late than creation of grid. So grid not able to get columns at time of grid creation
Please help.

```
reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data1'
                }
```

=============================================================

```
Ext.create('store', {storeId: this.storeId, gridHeaderMain:new Array()}).load({
            scope: this,
            gridHeaderMain: this.gridHeaderMain,
            callback: function(records, operation, success) {

                if (operation.success) {
                    console.log(operation.response.result);}}});
```

================================================================

console.log(Ext.getStore(this.storeId).gridHeaderMain); //UNDEFINED

==================================================================

## then grid creation code comes...

So this delay make impossible to set columns in grid

Comment: You should use reconfigure() for this: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769482/retrieve-gridpanel-model-store-columns-dynamically-from-server-side