# EXTJS Grid daynamic columns from Store data

Tags: php, extjs

I am facing issue in EXT JS GRID which is getting data from store.

My store take 3 sec to fetch data from php files as there are lot of records and processing in back end.

While store is loading, grid gets created.

Though grid get proper data as I have written root in store proxy.and data get populated in grid

```
reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'gridData'
        }
```

But now my issue is , I have return multidimensional array from php backend one is `gridData` and other is `gridDataColumns`.

My task is to generate store columns dynamically from store data.

When store get fully loaded at that time I dont have control on `columns:[]` of grid , as the code have already executed.

can any one please help me with this? thanks in advance.

I want to create dynamic columns in grid from store data

Comment: This has already been answered [there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18769482/1387519).

Comment: Please add this to answer. I want to accept it. this is what i needed

Comment: Glad I could help, and that's nice from you but I think it's better to avoid creating a duplicate. Upvoting the other answer will probably be more useful to people searching for this information in the future.

Comment: Ok...sure I appreciate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the perfect solution

[Retrieve GridPanel model/store/columns dynamically from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769482/retrieve-gridpanel-model-store-columns-dynamically-from-server-side)